# gccのコンパイルエラー: error adding symbol : file in wrong format

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu, gcc

Ubuntu 16.04, gcc 5.4.0 の環境でコンパイルしているのですが、エラーになってしまいます。

**実行コマンド:**

```
gcc -T link.ls -march i486 -m32 -o haribote.hrb bootpack.c hankaku.c naskfunc.o -lc
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
libgcc_s.o:error adding symbol : file in wrong format
```

なお、`-T link.ls` を外すとうまくコンパイルできます。

リンカスクリプトは以下の通りです。

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary");
    
SECTIONS
{
    .head 0x0 : {
        LONG(0x64 * 1024)  /*  0 : stack+.data+heap の大きさ（4KBの倍数） */
        LONG(0x69726148)      /*  4 : シグネチャ "Hari" */
        LONG(0)               /*  8 : mmarea の大きさ（4KBの倍数） */
        LONG(0x310000)        /* 12 : スタック初期値＆.data転送先 */
        LONG(SIZEOF(.data))   /* 16 : .dataサイズ */
        LONG(LOADADDR(.data)) /* 20 : .dataの初期値列のファイル位置 */
        LONG(0xE9000000)      /* 24 : 0xE9000000 */
        LONG(main - 0x20) /* 28 : エントリアドレス - 0x20 */
        LONG(0)               /* 32 : heap領域（malloc領域）開始アドレス */
    }

    .text : { *(.text) }

    .data 0x310000 : AT ( ADDR(.text) + SIZEOF(.text) ) {
        *(.data)
        *(.rodata*)
        *(.bss)
    }

    /DISCARD/ : { *(.eh_frame) }

}
```

Comment: `OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")` となっていますが、これは `OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386")` ではないでしょうか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。早速の所試して見ましたが、elf形式だとデータがオーバーラップしてしまいます。リンカはヘッダをつけるだけですので、できればバイナリ形式でコンパイルしたいと思っていますが、どうすれば宜しいでしょうか

Comment: `-N` オプションを付けてみてはどうでしょう。`gcc -N -T link.ls ...`

Comment: ありがとうございます今度はcannot find -lgcc_sが出てきましたが、これならなんとかなりそうです。早速試してみます。

Comment: お疲れ様です。いろいろ実行した結果、今度はcannot find -libgccと出てきました

Comment: @metropolis cannot find -libgccというエラーが出てきました。32ビットgccライブラリもインストールしましたので、原因が分からなくて困っております。度々の質問申し訳ございませんが、このエラーのどのように解決すれば宜しいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

libgcc を入れたはずなのに `cannnot find -libgcc` とエラーが出たのであれば、シンボリックリンクが貼れていないかもしれません。

対応策が書いてあるブログを見つけたので参考になれば。

[makeするとライブラリが入っているのに /usr/lib/ld: cannot find と怒られる問題](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/cou929_la/20080718/1216391301)

Comment: ありがとうございます。結局は自分でsprintfを創る事になりました＞＜